# Excel VBA Duplicates in one columns unique in another

Tags: vba, excel

I have been attempting to solve this for a couple of days and have been able not come up with or find a similar solution. I am trying to highlight duplicates in a single column where their are distinct values in another.

For example occasionally in column G there are duplicate names but they only need to be marked(highlighted) when the value column D is unique. So using the example below the end result should only highlight Elizabeth Moore.

```
Column D    Column G
116023339   Alan Fluder
116023339   Alan Fluder
116023347   Elizabeth Moore
116025757   Elizabeth Moore
116025048   A. Lavoie
```

If it helps below is the code I used as my starting point.

```
Sub test()

Dim cel As Variant
Dim myCell As Variant
Dim myrng As Range
Dim myRange As Range
Dim CellValue As Long

Set myrng = Range("G2:G" & Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
Set myRange = Range("D2:D" & Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

For Each cel In myrng
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(myrng, cel) > 1 Then
        For Each myCell In myRange
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(myRange, myCell) = 1        Then
                myCell.Offset(0, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            End If
        Next myCell
    End If
Next cel

End Sub
```

I should add that my current solution now is to separate the loops where one highlights all the column G dups then the second loop unhighlights where column D is duped.

Comment: You could do this with a formula: `=COUNTIFS(D:D,D2,G:G,G2)<>COUNTIF(G:G,G2)`  Will be TRUE for cases matching your description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use formulas @Tim's suggestion works well. To fix the VBA:

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Const ROW_OFFSET As Byte = 2

    Dim cel As Range
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim cRow As Long
    Dim lRow As Long

    Set rng1 = Range("G" & ROW_OFFSET & ":G" & Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    Set rng2 = Range("D" & ROW_OFFSET & ":D" & Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        For Each cel In rng1
            If .CountIf(rng1, cel) > 1 Then
                If .CountIf(rng2, rng2.Cells(cel.Row - (ROW_OFFSET - 1), 1)) = 1 Then
                    cel.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                End If
            End If
        Next cel
    End With
End Sub
```

---

The inner For is not needed if columns are synchronized

I used the ROW_OFFSET constant to emphasize the alignment between columns

.

[image: Dupes and Uniques]